# Using redirection to write a command using a file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I´m starting to use Ubuntu as my secondary OS and I´m creating a script which writes the current IP configuration in a file using redirection (with the command `$sudo ifconfig -a > /etc/scripts/current-ipaddress`) and the next thing I want to do is using one of the values written in that external file for the next command, if possible.

For example, lets say I run `$sudo ifconfig -a > /etc/scripts/current-ipaddress` and the IP address for eth0 is 192.168.1.203 and the next thing I want to do is making this IP the static one using the command `$sudo ifconfig eth0 x.x.x.x`. The idea is substituting this x.x.x.x with the real IP (which will be extracted from the file it was written using redirections previously). How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```bash
theip=$(cat /etc/scripts/current-ipaddress | awk '/^eth0:/{flag = 1; next} flag == 1 && / inet / {print $2} /^[^ ]/ {flag=0}')
```

Explanations:

- `cat filename`: print the file content
- `awk`: work on text input flow from pipe (the file content)

  - `/^eth0:/{flag = 1; next}`: search for line who start with `eth0:` token and put value `1` in variable `flag` then treat the next line.
  - `flag == 1 && / inet / {print $2}`: if variable `flag` equal to `1` and line contains `inet` token, then print the second field (by default the field separators and spaces)
  - `/^[^ ]/ {flag=0}`: if line do not starts by a space, put `0` value in the `flag` variable
- `theip=$(...command...)`: put the command standard output in the variable `theip`